# Trim space along with hyphen from a string at start and end of the string

Tags: javascript

I have a string in JavaScript like `var s="test - test1"` and sometimes `s=" - test1"` and sometimes just `" -"`. I want to remove the space and hyphen only if it's present at the start and end of the string. Meaning, we should not do anything for the 1st case `s="test - test1"`.

**Expected Result:**

```js
var s="test - test1"
```

result should be `"test - test1"`

```js
var s=" - test1"
```

result should be `"test1"`

```js
" -"
```

result should be `""`

Could you guys help me on this?

Comment: What is the expected result?

Comment: Have you looked at using String.prototype.replace() with a regular expression?

Answer (score 1):

```js
  
var s="test - test1";
var reg = new RegExp(/-$|^-/ig);
console.log(s.trim().replace(reg,"").trim());
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to remove all spaces with the following hyphens, then just replace it with this method `.replace(/ -/g,'')`.

```js
var s="test - test1";
console.log(s.replace(/ -/g,''))
s = " - test1";
console.log(s.replace(/ -/g,''))
s = " -";
console.log(s.replace(/ -/g,''))
s="test - test1 - test2";
console.log(s.replace(/ -/g,''))
```

Comment: If ' - ' comes in the middle, I don't want to make any changes. Unfortunately this method won't work.

Comment: What input and output do you want?

Comment: The question states at the end and start. Ie trimming does not do anything ti the middle of a string.

Answer (score 0):

A regex-only solution (try-its were modified a bit to avoid messing with line breaks):

```js
function removeLeadingTrailingHyphens_match(s) {
  return s.match(/^(?:\s*-\s*)?(.*?)(?:\s*-\s*)?$/)[1];
}
```

Explanation:

```
^             # Match at the start of string
(?:\s*-\s*)?  # 0+ spaces, then a hyphen, collectively optional
(.*?)         # then anything surrounded by whitespaces, which we capture (and return),
(?:\s*-\s*)?  # another optional pair of hyphen and spaces
$             # right before the end of string
```

Try it [on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/qKAtJF/1).

Try it:

```js
console.config({ maximize: true });

function removeLeadingTrailingHyphens_match(s) {
  return s.match(/^(?:\s*-\s*)?(.*?)(?:\s*-\s*)?$/)[1];
}

const testcases = [
  'test - test1',
  ' - test1',
  'test - ',
  ' -',
  ' - test -'
];

testcases.forEach(
  testcase => console.log(`'${removeLeadingTrailingHyphens_match(testcase)}'`)
);
```

```html
<script src="https://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>
```

...or, using `.replace()`:

```js
function removeLeadingTrailingHyphens_replace(s) {
  return s.replace(/^\s*-\s*|\s*-\s*$/g, '');
}
```

Explanation:

```
^\s*-\s*      # Match either a space-surrounded hyphen at the start of string
|             # or
\s*-\s*$      # at the end (which we replace with nothing).
```

Try it [on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/qKAtJF/2).

Try it:

```js
console.config({ maximize: true });

function removeLeadingTrailingHyphens_replace(s) {
  return s.replace(/^\s*-\s*|\s*-\s*$/g, '');
}

const testcases = [
  'test - test1',
  ' - test1',
  'test - ',
  ' -',
  ' - test -'
];

testcases.forEach(
  testcase => console.log(`'${removeLeadingTrailingHyphens_replace(testcase)}'`)
);
```

```html
<script src="https://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: How does this regex  help? A code-only (and almost link-only) answer is not helpful.

Comment: @key Explanation added.